Changing Count to Age using Jupyter Notebook
I'm currently working on our project on Jupyter Notebook but along the way I encounter some minor problems. As shown in the graph the age is correct but I want to change the depression part and the other graph that displays "count" at the left side of it as "Age" and the numbers should be the list of age mentioned at the first graph (Distribution of Age). Is there a way to this? here is my sample code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": list("ABCDEF"),
    "Age": [18, 20, 20, 25, 30, 30, 35],
    "Depression": [1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 5]
})

# Loop to create and display histograms with a larger figure size
for i in df.select_dtypes(include="number").columns:
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))  # Adjust the width and height as needed
    sns.histplot(data=df, x=i)
    plt.title(f'Distribution of {i}')  # Add a title to each plot for clarity
    plt.show()



Very unclear question... [ask] and [mre]

If I'm understanding correctly, you have a Depression column with integer values 1 to 5, and Age that are integers from 18 to 50. What is unclear is what you want on the x axis and what you want on the y axis, as of now your code displays the histogram of each field, i.e. the number of entries for each value of your field i, so you'll have count on the y-axis and i on each of the x-axes

I'm really sorry for the unclear statement, I'm just new to this kind of project let me make things more simpler. The first graph (Distribution of Age) is correct it displays the counts of the respondents to its corresponding age. My problem is at the second on (Distribution of depression) I want to change the counts into the number of age that's it. Is it possible?

I think that you might want something like sns.histplot(data=df, x="Age", hue="Depression", multiple="stack"), outside of the for loop ; tell us if it works and if it corresponds more to what you want.

sorry but it still not working, but thank you for the help.

When you say that it still not working, what do you mean ? do you have an error ? or it didn't provide you the right result ?

In your question, please include a sketch of what your goal second plot might look like. This would help a lot to explain what you are looking for.

It's very unclear what you want to get from the graphs. If you want to know some information about age in each level of depression, you can use sns.barplot(df, x='Depression', y='Age'). But without further clarification of your expectations, it's hard to give you an answer.
